# OpenCV resize() result is wrong?

Tags: python, opencv, interpolation, bilinear-interpolation

Sample program that upscales 2x2 matrix to 5x5 using bilinear interpolation.
Result that OpenCV produces has artifacts at the borders for such simple case.

```
gy, gx = np.mgrid[0:2, 0:2]
gx = np.float32(gx)
print(gx)
res = cv2.resize(gx,(5,5), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]

[[ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]]
```

Expected output:

```
  [[0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1
    0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1
    0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1
    0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1
    0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1]]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think it is similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104609/interpolating-1-dimensional-array-using-opencv?rq=1)

Comment: This seems interesting... found a solution?

Comment: I have modified OpenCV to get what I want avoiding 0.5 pixel shift.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpolating 1 dimensional array using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104609/interpolating-1-dimensional-array-using-opencv)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I tested with other image processing libraries (scikit-image, Pillow and Matlab) and none of them return the expected result.

Odds are this behavior is due to the method to perform the bi-linear interpolation to get efficient results or somehow a convention rather than a bug in my opinion.

I have posted a sample code to perform image resizing with a bi-linear interpolation (check if everything is ok of course, *I am not sure how to properly handle the image indexes*...) that outputs the expected result.

---

*Partial answer to the question.*

### What is the output of some other image processing libraries?

#### scikit-image

The Python module [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) contains lot of image processing algorithms. Here the outputs of the [`skimage.transform.resize`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) method (`skimage.__version__:  0.12.3`):

- `mode='constant'` (default)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize

image = np.array( [
                [0., 1.],
                [0., 1.]
    ] )
print 'image:\n', image

image_resized = resize(image, (5,5), order=1, mode='constant')
print 'image_resized:\n', image_resized
```

Result:

```
image:
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
image_resized:
[[ 0.    0.07  0.35  0.63  0.49]
 [ 0.    0.1   0.5   0.9   0.7 ]
 [ 0.    0.1   0.5   0.9   0.7 ]
 [ 0.    0.1   0.5   0.9   0.7 ]
 [ 0.    0.07  0.35  0.63  0.49]]
```

- `mode='edge'`

Result:

```
image:
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
image_resized:
[[ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]
 [ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]
 [ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]
 [ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]
 [ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]]
```

- `mode='symmetric'`

Result:

```
image:
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
image_resized:
[[ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]
 [ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]
 [ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]
 [ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]
 [ 0.   0.1  0.5  0.9  1. ]]
```

- `mode='reflect'`

Result:

```
image:
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
image_resized:
[[ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]]
```

- `mode='wrap'`

Result:

```
image:
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
image_resized:
[[ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.1  0.5  0.9  0.7]]
```

As you can see, the default resize mode (`constant`) produces a different output but the edge mode returns the same result than OpenCV. None of the resize mode produces the expected result thought.

More information about [Interpolation: Edge Modes](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_edge_modes.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-transform-plot-edge-modes-py).

This picture sums up all the results in our case:

[image: edge modes]

#### Pillow

[Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/)

> is the friendly PIL fork by Alex Clark and Contributors. PIL is the
>   Python Imaging Library by Fredrik Lundh and Contributors.

What about [`PIL.Image.Image.resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) (`PIL.__version__:  4.0.0`)?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = np.array( [
                [0., 1.],
                [0., 1.]
    ] )
print 'image:\n', image

image_pil = Image.fromarray(image)
image_resized_pil = image_pil.resize((5,5), resample=Image.BILINEAR)
print 'image_resized_pil:\n', np.asarray(image_resized_pil, dtype=np.float)
```

Result:

```
image:
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
image_resized_pil:
[[ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.89999998  1.        ]]
```

`Pillow` image resizing matches the output of the OpenCV library.

#### Matlab

Matlab proposes a toolbox named [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html). The function [`imresize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) in this toolbox allows to resize image.

Code:

```
image = zeros(2,1,'double');
image(1,2) = 1;
image(2,2) = 1;
image
image_resize = imresize(image, [5 5], 'bilinear')
```

Result:

```
image =

     0     1
     0     1


image_resize =

         0    0.1000    0.5000    0.9000    1.0000
         0    0.1000    0.5000    0.9000    1.0000
         0    0.1000    0.5000    0.9000    1.0000
         0    0.1000    0.5000    0.9000    1.0000
         0    0.1000    0.5000    0.9000    1.0000
```

Again, it is not the expected output with Matlab but the same result with the two previous examples.

### Custom bi-linear image resize method

#### Basic principle

See this Wikipedia article on [Bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) for more complete information.

This figure should basically illustrates what happens when up-scaling from a `2x2` image to a `4x4` image:

[image: upscaling]

With a nearest neighbor interpolation, the destination pixel at `(0,0)` will get the value of the source pixel at `(0,0)` as well as the pixels at `(0,1)`, `(1,0)` and `(1,1)`.

With a bi-linear interpolation, the destination pixel at `(0,0)` will get a value which is a linear combination of the 4 neighbors in the source image:

[image: Wikipedia: BilinearInterpolation.svg.png]

> The four red dots show the data points and the green dot is the point
>   at which we want to interpolate.

`R1` is calculated as: `R1 = ((x2 – x)/(x2 – x1))*Q11 + ((x – x1)/(x2 – x1))*Q21`.

`R2` is calculated as: `R2 = ((x2 – x)/(x2 – x1))*Q12 + ((x – x1)/(x2 – x1))*Q22`.

Finally, `P` is calculated as a weighted average of `R1` and `R2`: `P = ((y2 – y)/(y2 – y1))*R1 + ((y – y1)/(y2 – y1))*R2`.

Using coordinates normalized between `[0, 1]` simplifies the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation#Unit_Square).

#### C++ implementation

This blog post ([Resizing Images With Bicubic Interpolation](http://blog.demofox.org/2015/08/15/resizing-images-with-bicubic-interpolation/)) contains C++ code to perform image resizing with a bi-linear interpolation.

This is my own adaptation (some modifications about the indexes compared to the original code, **not sure if it is correct**) of the code to work with `cv::Mat`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

float lerp(const float A, const float B, const float t) {
  return A * (1.0f - t) + B * t;
}

template <typename Type>
Type resizeBilinear(const cv::Mat &src, const float u, const float v, const float xFrac, const float yFrac) {
  int u0 = (int) u;
  int v0 = (int) v;

  int u1 = (std::min)(src.cols-1, (int) u+1);
  int v1 = v0;

  int u2 = u0;
  int v2 = (std::min)(src.rows-1, (int) v+1);

  int u3 = (std::min)(src.cols-1, (int) u+1);
  int v3 = (std::min)(src.rows-1, (int) v+1);

  float col0 = lerp(src.at<Type>(v0, u0), src.at<Type>(v1, u1), xFrac);
  float col1 = lerp(src.at<Type>(v2, u2), src.at<Type>(v3, u3), xFrac);
  float value = lerp(col0, col1, yFrac);

  return cv::saturate_cast<Type>(value);
}

template <typename Type>
void resize(const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst) {
  float scaleY = (src.rows - 1) / (float) (dst.rows - 1);
  float scaleX = (src.cols - 1) / (float) (dst.cols - 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < dst.rows; i++) {
    float v = i * scaleY;
    float yFrac = v - (int) v;

    for (int j = 0; j < dst.cols; j++) {
      float u = j * scaleX;
      float xFrac = u - (int) u;

      dst.at<Type>(i, j) = resizeBilinear<Type>(src, u, v, xFrac, yFrac);
    }
  }
}

void resize(const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst, const int width, const int height) {
  if (width < 2 || height < 2 || src.cols < 2 || src.rows < 2) {
    std::cerr << "Too small!" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  dst = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, src.type());

  switch (src.type()) {
    case CV_8U:
      resize<uchar>(src, dst);
      break;

    case CV_64F:
      resize<double>(src, dst);
      break;

    default:
      std::cerr << "Src type is not supported!" << std::endl;
      break;
  }
}

int main() {
  cv::Mat img = (cv::Mat_<double>(2,2) << 0, 1, 0, 1);
  std::cout << "img:\n" << img << std::endl;
  cv::Mat img_resize;
  resize(img, img_resize, 5, 5);
  std::cout << "img_resize=\n" << img_resize << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It produces:

```
img:
[0, 1;
 0, 1]
img_resize=
[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1;
 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1;
 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1;
 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1;
 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
```

### Conclusion

In my opinion, it is unlikely that the OpenCV `resize()` function is wrong as none of the others image processing libraries I can test produce the expected output and moreover can produce the same OpenCV output with the good parameter.

I tested against two Python modules (scikit-image and Pillow) as they are easy to use and oriented about image processing. I was also able to test with Matlab and its image processing toolbox.

A rough custom implementation of the bi-linear interpolation for image resizing produces the expected result. Two possibilities for me could explain this behavior:

- the difference is inherent to the method these image processing libraries use rather than a bug (maybe they use a method to resize images efficiently with some loss compared to a strict bi-linear implementation?)?
- it is a somehow a convention to interpolate properly excluding the border?

These libraries are open-source and one can explore into their source code to understand where the discrepancy comes from.

The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124412/6055233) shows that the interpolation works only between the two original blue dots but I cannot explain why this behavior.

#### Why this answer?

This answer, even if it partially answers the OP question, is a good way for me to summarize the few things I found about this topic. I believe also it could help in some way other people who may found this.

Comment: "Pillow image resizing matches the output of the OpenCV library." No longer. Pillow implementation was fixed and now is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As I will explain below, the output:

```
[[ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.9         1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.9         1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.9         1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.9         1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.1         0.5         0.9         1.        ]]
```

would be the correct solution. So while `opencv` has small rounding errors, it is mostly correct.

The reason: your input image doesn't assume an image with the values "0" and "1" in the corners of the image, but in the center of the pixels.

So this the wrong model of what your 2x2 image looks like:

[image]

Instead, your image looks like this, with the "colors" defined in the red points. Everything to the left of the center of the left two pixels is just white, and everything to the right of the center of the right two pixels is just black, and values between the pixel centers are interpolated:

[image]

Converting the image to 5x5 pixels:

[image]

and looking at the centers of the pixels, you see how you would get "0.1" and "0.9" instead of "0.25" and "0.75"

Comment: It's stupid, but this is indeed OpenCV's model, as explained in the documentation. I say it's stupid, because if the top-left pixel is (0,0), then the top-left pixel in the interpolated image has some different coordinates. At least in every sensical model I've seen, the pixel coordinates are the coordinates of the centroid of the pixel, where you placed the red dots. The center of the top-left pixel shifts in the OpenCV model. This is why it's unintuitive to many people.

Comment: I disagree, I think it's not stupid but the sensible thing to do (which also all image editors like Photoshop etc. are doing). It allows scaling an image without "cropping", it keeping the full content the same (as opposed to single pixels). it can be unintuitive though, I agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

Jan provided a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70068668/21537917) explaining the reasoning behind the behaviour of [`cv::resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d), but I would like to add that there are other `opencv` functions that can be used to achieve the result that the OP expected. One option is to use [`cv::remap`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4):

```python
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
    ],
    dtype=np.float32,
)

orig_height, orig_width = a.shape
scaled_width = 5
scaled_height = 5

x = np.linspace(0, orig_width - 1, scaled_width, dtype=np.float32)
y = np.linspace(0, orig_height - 1, scaled_height, dtype=np.float32)
map_x, map_y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

scaled = cv.remap(a, map_x, map_y, interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Another option is to use [`cv::warpAffine`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983):

```python
M = np.array(
    [
        [(scaled_width - 1) / (orig_width - 1), 0, 0],
        [0, (scaled_height - 1) / (orig_height - 1), 0],
    ],
    dtype=np.float32,
)

scaled = cv.warpAffine(a, M, dsize=(scaled_width, scaled_height), flags=cv.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Both functions produce the expected output for the OP's example input:

```
scaled:
[[0., 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.],
 [0., 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.],
 [0., 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.],
 [0., 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.],
 [0., 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.]],
```

However, `interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR` doesn't always produce the expected result (e.g, when scaling the example input to the size (4, 4)). Perhaps this could be fixed by [implementing support for `cv2.INTER_LINEAR_EXACT`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12700).

If using `scipy` is an alternative there are many more options:

```python
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
scaled = zoom(a, scaled_width / orig_width, order=1, prefilter=False)
```

```python
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates
scaled = map_coordinates(a, np.meshgrid(y, x, indexing="ij"), order=1)
```

```python
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
interp = RegularGridInterpolator(
    (np.arange(orig_height), np.arange(orig_width)),
    a,
    method="linear",
)
scaled = interp(tuple(np.meshgrid(y, x, indexing="ij")))
```

```python
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
interp = RectBivariateSpline(
    range(orig_height),
    range(orig_width),
    a,
    bbox=[0, orig_height - 1, 0, orig_width - 1],
    kx=1,
    ky=1,
    s=0,
)
scaled = interp(y, x)
```